# Shell script to filter string from a data stream and output to screen

Tags: text-processing, tail, streaming

I am trying to make it easy to tail a log file and print to the screen only the output of a single field.

I have the log file that looks like this on a Linux machine:

```
2022-10-21 16:00:08;areq_in=0;areq_qavg=0;areq_qmax=0;areq_sent=0;ares_out=0;ares_out_err=0;ares_out_ok=0;ares_qavg=0;ares_qmax=0;ares
_recv=0;ares_tavg=0;ares_tmax=0;creq_out=0;creq_qavg=0;creq_qmax=0;creq_recv=0;cres_in=0;cres_qavg=0;cres_qmax=0;cres_sent=0;lic_rej=0
;lic_use=0;mbr_from=0;mbr_to=0;mreject=0;mreject_conn=0;msys_recv=0;msys_sent=0;
```

Each line in the log consists of `;`-separated fields, most of which are in the "key=value" form.

So what I am trying to do is only print the field whose "key" name is `creq_recv` on the screen.

I took this script from someone's fix but I think I am missing something.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
creq_recv=$1
my_variable=`tail -f stats_2022102116.log | awk -F: -v creq_recv="$1" '$1 == creq_recv {$1=$1; print}' stats_2022102116.log`
echo "$my_variable"
```

Because the output is empty

```
[root@priti ]$ ./chk_conn_log.sh
    
[root@priti ]$
```

The output should print on screen whatever value `creq_recv` is. For example, like below

```
creq_recv=12
creq_recv=34
creq_recv=65
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited my original post. Sorry i just tried everything and at an exasperation wrote this entry. I usually look for solution here [and work from there and always manage to find a solution], but this is the second time in a long time i have posted a problem. Yes, i just want the output of the value of creq_recv, whatever the value may be in the log.

Comment: But your post shows you don't just want the value (`12`, `34` etc.), you also want `creq_recv=`, is that not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want just with `grep` with the `-o` option to only print the matching portion of the line and `-P` or `-E` for PCRE or extended regular expressions respectively, which let us use `[^;]+` for "one or more non-; characters":

```
tail -f stats_2022102116.log | grep -oP '(?<=^|;)creq_recv=[^;]+'
```

Or, safer in case we can have other field names that end with `creq_recv`:

```
tail -f stats_2022102116.log | grep -oP '(^|;)\Kcreq_recv=[^;]+'
```

Your `awk` was failing because `-v creq_recv="$1"`  means "set the value of the awk variable `creq_recv` to the value of the first argument passed to the script". But since you are launching the script with no arguments (`./chk_conn_log.sh`), `$1` is empty, so `creq_recv` is also empty.

In any case, that wouldn't have worked, even if the variable were being set. Both because the `awk` script was wrong and because `tail -f` will never exit unless you stop it, so the `echo` wouldn't be executed. You wanted something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -f stats_2022102116.log | 
    awk -F';'  '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ if ($i ~ /^creq_recv=/) { print $i } } }'
```

No `echo`, nothing but the `tail` and the corrected awk script. But just use the `grep` command above, it's much simpler.

Comment: Yes, this totally worked!

i got what I wanted!!!!

`[root@priti ]$ cat stats_2022102118.log | awk -F';'  '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ if ($i ~ /^creq_recv=/) { print $i}}}'
creq_recv=0
creq_recv=0
creq_recv=0
creq_recv=0`

Comment: @PritiPatel no need to `cat`. If you don't want `tail -f` to watch the file, just give the file to awk directly: `awk -F';'  '{...}' stats_2022102118.log`. But, really, the `grep` approach is simpler.

Comment: The `|;` in `grep -oP '(?=^|;)creq_recv=[^;]+'` does not make sense, `creq_recv` will never start with `;`, it will always start with `c`. ITYM `(?<=` instead of `(?=`

Comment: Argh! Of course I do, @StéphaneChazelas, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution you tried contains several problems that lead to the undesired behavior you experience.

1. Your script expects a command-line argument (`$1` at the "bash" level) that you don't seem to specify when calling it as `./chk_conn_log.sh`
2. You script copies that (unspecified = empty) value to a *shell* variable `creq_recv`. So, `creq_recv` *as far as your shell is concerned*, is an empty variable.
3. You want to filter the *ongoing* output of a process via `tail`, but assign the result to a shell variable that you later print with `echo`. This will not work, because the variable will only ever be filled when both processes terminate. However, if the logfile is not written to anymore, `tail` will simply wait for new input - so it will never terminate, and your script *would* literally be stuck there, however,
4. Although you want to pipe the output of `tail` to `awk`, you also explicitly state the log file as argument, so `awk` will simply run over the content of the file *as it looks like at the moment the script is called*, where it likely doesn't yet contain any lines, and then terminate. So your variable `my_variable` is empty, and your script's output, too.

Even so,

5. You say (and the example shows) that the log file is `;`-separated, but you instruct `awk` to use `:` as separator.
6. You set a *awk variable* `creq_recv` to the (unspecified) command-line argument, and inside the `awk` program check whether the *first* `:`-separated field is equal to the content of the *awk* variable `creq_recv`. However, that variable is empty (see above), and the "field" will contain the string `2022-10-21 16` (the date/time up to the first `:`), so for many reasons the condition will never be met, meaning that even if the log file already contained lines when the script was called, the output would still be empty.
7. You would print the entire line, not only the field that says `creq_recv=xx`.

---

That said, what *I think you want to achieve* can be done as follows:

```
tail -f stats_2022102116.log | awk -F';' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (index($i,"creq_recv=")==1) print $i}}'
```

- This will set the field separator to `;`.
- It will then, for every (incoming) input line, iterate over all such fields, and if the field starts with the string `creq_recv=`, print that field.

Note that I chose to use a literal string comparison instead of a regular expression match, because (in the general case) that allows you to look for strings that contain characters with special meaning in regular expressions without the hassle of escaping them. If you need regular expression matching (which is not the case here, according to your post), you can change

```
if (index($i,"creq_recv=")==1)
```

to

```
if ($i ~ /your regular expression/)
```

Comment: I read your comment again and the regular expression bit was really helpful!

I am not sure how to quote this, but here is a sample script I created to catch a different type of word in the log

`#!/bin/bash
LOG=path_to_log

tail -f $LOG/path_to_log/log_$(date +%Y%m%d%H).log | awk -F';' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ "ERR:") print $i}}'`

Comment: @PritiPatel Yes, this is what I was referring to. Please note that for efficiency reasons, the regular expression should be contained in `/ ... /` and not in `" ... "` because of how `awk` handles these items internally.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
#recover all key/value pairs:

~$ cat file | raku -e 'my @a = lines>>.split(";", :skip-empty)>>.[1..*].flat;  \
                       my %hash;  for @a>>.split("=") {%hash.=append: $_};  \
                      .say for %hash.sort;'
```

```perl
#recover values for specific key:

~$ cat file | raku -e 'my @a = lines>>.split(";", :skip-empty)>>.[1..*].flat; \
                       my %hash;  for @a>>.split("=") {%hash.=append: $_}; \
                       say %hash<creq_recv>;'
```

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a Perl-family programming language. The question practically begs for a key-value solution, and Raku doesn't disappoint.

For the above two code examples, they are identical except for the last statement. Briefly, `lines` of the file are read in, which has the effect of chomping off  trailing `\n` newlines by default. Then this input is split on `;` semicolons to produce element that are `[1..*]` indexed to remove the first (time/date) element, `flat`tened, and stored in the `@a` array. Then the elements of `@a` are are `>>` individually split on `=` equal-sign. These resulting elements are `append`ed *en mass* to the `%hash`. Raku when given input in this manner makes a key/value pair out of every successive two elements.

In the first code example, all keys/value pairs are returned. In the second code example, only the values associated with the `creq_recv` key are returned.

Sample Input:

```
2022-10-21 16:00:08;areq_in=0;areq_qavg=0;areq_qmax=0;areq_sent=0;ares_out=0;ares_out_err=0;ares_out_ok=0;ares_qavg=0;ares_qmax=0;ares_recv=0;ares_tavg=0;ares_tmax=0;creq_out=0;creq_qavg=0;creq_qmax=0;creq_recv=0;cres_in=0;cres_qavg=0;cres_qmax=0;cres_sent=0;lic_rej=0;lic_use=0;mbr_from=0;mbr_to=0;mreject=0;mreject_conn=0;msys_recv=0;msys_sent=0;
```

Sample Output for first code example (second code example returns `0`):

```perl
areq_in => 0
areq_qavg => 0
areq_qmax => 0
areq_sent => 0
ares_out => 0
ares_out_err => 0
ares_out_ok => 0
ares_qavg => 0
ares_qmax => 0
ares_recv => 0
ares_tavg => 0
ares_tmax => 0
creq_out => 0
creq_qavg => 0
creq_qmax => 0
creq_recv => 0
cres_in => 0
cres_qavg => 0
cres_qmax => 0
cres_sent => 0
lic_rej => 0
lic_use => 0
mbr_from => 0
mbr_to => 0
mreject => 0
mreject_conn => 0
msys_recv => 0
msys_sent => 0
```

For a more informative return, use Raku's `=>` pair-constructor, changing the last statement to:

```perl
$_ = "creq_recv" andthen say $_ => %hash{$_};
```

...which returns:

```perl
creq_recv => 0
```

Finally, Raku implements `react` blocks, which can designed to receive a `Supply` (lets say, for example, `$*IN.lines` lines-received-via-StdIN), and `whenever` received, run code. Like so:

```perl
~$ tail -f test.log | raku -e 'react {whenever Supply( $*IN.lines ) {   \
                               my @a = $_.map( *.split(";", :skip-empty).[1..*] ).flat;  \
                               my %hash; for @a.map: *.split("=") { %hash.=append: $_ };  \
                               $_ = "creq_recv" andthen say $_ => %hash{$_} // Nil; } };'
creq_recv => 0
creq_recv => 0
^C
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/concurrency#react
https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap
https://docs.raku.org/routine/=%3E
https://raku.org

*PS: There's an absolutely stellar chapter on "Associatives" (i.e. Hashes and Maps) in brian d foy's book **Learning Perl6**.*

Comment: Thank you for this Raku scripts!  
The first script prints results in square brackets 
```areq_in => [0 0 0 0 0] areq_qavg => [0 0 0 0 0] areq_qmax => [0 0 0 0 0] 
```

and the second one prints result of creq_recv 
```cat stats_2022102613.log | raku -e 'my @a = slurp.chomp.split(/ \; /, :skip-empty); \ my %hash = @a.tail(*-1)>>.split("=", 2, :skip-empty).flat; \ say %hash<creq_recv>;' 0``` 
but it should print continuously the result of ```creq_recv=```

Comment: What happens if you pipe `tail -f stats_2022102116.log` into the second script?

Comment: I've updated the first two scripts to accept linewise input, instead of slurping-in input all at once. Additionally, I've also added a Raku `react` block script at the end. You should be able to get the result you want by `piping tail -f stats_2022102116.log` into the final script (i.e. *"...printing continuously the result of `creq_recv`"*.